# New installation of 12.04 unable to find autorun

Tags: installation, 12.04

I have Windows 7 and had a dual boot with Wubi.  I recently installed BackTrack 5 on my hard drive and in doing so messed up my Ubuntu 11.10, so I downloaded the new Ubuntu 12.04 and burned the image to a CD.  When I restart to the CD/DVD drive the GRUB loader comes up and not the Ubuntu install.

I have checked the contents of the image and all the files seem to be in order.  When I try to run from command in BT5r2 its unable to find autorun.  So I burned another disc and have the same problem.  It's unable to locate autorun and it wont autorun from restart and my BIOS is correct.  I even tried from USB and got 'unable to find OS'.

I don't have a Windows 7 install disc.  I am looking to do a full install of Ubuntu 12.04.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try making a bootable usb with the 12.04 iso?

Comment: yes and i get something along the lines of no operating system detected

Comment: i might have made the bootable usb wrong though, i sent the downloaded iso to the usb and set BIOS as boot from usb , i might need further instruction on making the usb properly bootable

Comment: Do you have another Ubuntu available near you? Then you can use its "Startup Disk creator" to create a bootable pen drive.

Comment: sorry , i do not my original ubuntu was a dual boot with wubi and upon my partitioning for BT5r2 i was unable to load my ubuntu

Comment: So I guess you have Windows available then. There is a utility called UNetbootin which you can use to make a bootable thumb drive. I haven't used it myself but most of the people around use that. Why not give that a shot?

Comment: yes i do, thank you for your input i will use UNetbootin to make a bootable thumb drive, hopefully that works,

Comment: ok i tried UNetbootin and when booted it says invalid or corrupt kernel image i'm going to assume there is something wrong with the file i downloaded from ubuntu earlier or somehow i corrupted it myself any other suggestions couldnt hurt , i will try another download and burn the image again

Comment: Perform the md5checksum on your downloaded iso file to make sure that it is not corrupt. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. It seems the Roxio image burner for Windows doesn't set the disc up right, so I used isoburner and the CD loads perfectly. Ubuntu 12.04 then installed perfectly from the newly burned disc. Thanks for your advice.